# how do I solve this error:'Tensor' object is not callable when I want to fill a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

when I want to fill a tensor with the value of another tensor it produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 80, in 
>       wtm_Fill=wfill(temp(0,0))
>
> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

```
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
#conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e', kernel_initializer='Orthogonal',bias_initializer='glorot_uniform')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
#DrO1=Dropout(0.25,name='Dro1')(BN)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)

#-----------------------adding w---------------------------------------

temp=tf.reshape(wtm,(28,28))
wfill=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.fill([28,28],x))
wtm_Fill=wfill(temp(0,0))
add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])
```

I need sth like this:
wtm=

```
0 1 1
1 1 0
0 0 1
```

wtm(0,0)=0 so I want to produce this
 new tensor with shape(28,28,1)

```
0 0 0 ... 0
.
. 0 0 ... 0
0 0 0 ... 0

from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise,Dropout,BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AtrousConv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;
#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------
w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
wt_random=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_random=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
wt_expand=wt_expand.reshape((1,28,28,1))

#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)


temp=tf.reshape(wtm,(28,28))
wfill=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.fill([28,28],x))
wtm_Fill=wfill(temp[0,0])
add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm_Fill])

#wfill=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.fill([28,28],x))
#value=wtm[0][0][0]
#x=tf.fill((28,28,1),value)
#add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
#encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,x])
#encoder=Model(inputs=[image,wtm], outputs= encoded_merged ,name='encoder')
#encoder.summary()

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 

model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_noise)
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw5)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)  
w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

w_extraction.summary()
```

this is my new code but after implementation it produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 106, in 
>       model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 93, in **init**
>       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 231, in _init_graph_network
>       self.inputs, self.outputs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1366, in _map_graph_network
>       tensor_index=tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1325, in build_map
>       node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: I think you just need to change `wtm_Fill=wfill(temp(0,0))` to `wtm_Fill=wfill(temp[0,0])`. Note square brackets (`[]`) must be used to index a tensor.

Comment: I do this, but it produces this error, I put above.

Answer (score 0):

To produce such tensor you need to:
Suppose tensor shape is (28,28,1)

```
value = tensor[0][0][0]
wtm = tf.fill((10,10,1), value)
```

This will output tensor of shape (10,10,1) filled with value

Comment: if I do this 
value=wtm[0][0][0]
x=tf.fill((28,28,1),value)
add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,x])

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-36-a8ff3a017fdf>", line 26, in <module>
    x=tf.fill((28,28,1),value)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2979, in fill
    "Fill", dims=dims, value=value, name=name)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1631, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'Fill_3' (op: 'Fill') with input shapes: [3], [1].

Comment: In this case wtm is a placeholder tensor, which means you should feed data to it with model.fit function. You need to specify needed shape, and do all the resizing with actual data you're going to feed to the model

Comment: I updated my code and put the whole code here. I changed it based on your explanations but it produces the above error. could you please tell what is the problem and why?

Comment: the problem is in this piece of code `temp=tf.reshape(wtm,(28,28))
wfill=layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.fill([28,28],x))
wtm_Fill=wfill(temp[0,0])
add_const = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm_Fill])`
Without it you model should compile.  First of all you can't just reshape (28,28,1) to `tf.reshape(wtm,(28,28))`. It has a dimension mismatch and you're trying to reshape keras layer, which makes no sense. All you have to do is provide dimensions you want to deconv1. And do all the reshapes with data not layers

Comment: yes, I know this part produces the error and my code works without this part. but I need the values of wtm and finally I could not understand how can I access to each value of wtm, because I want to make a new tensor that all of its values are the same as one value of wtm and I add this part of code to do this but I do not know how and this is also does not work. please tell me how can I access to each value of wtm and do the things I said. I reshape wtm to (28,28) because I thought with this change I can access to its values, but it was wrong:((

Comment: `wtm=layers.Input((28,28,1))` this is not a tensor, but a keras layer object. here you just need to specify shape. You should only reshape data, which you'll pass to `model.fit` later

Comment: sorry, could you please explain more. as I mentioned before I am a very beginner. you said this is a layer, not a tensor this means I can not access to wtm( i,j)? because I do sth like this wtmN=Kr.layers.Lambda(K.tile,arguments={'n':(1,7,7,1)})(wtm) on wtm before but now I do not know how to solve this?! could you please tell me about solution?